# Revert To Previous Version In Github, only editing in Github

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I am probably missing something very simple somewhere...

What I would like to do is revert to a previous version of a READ.ME file which I have **only edited in Github**.  Everything I have found to do this involves using the Git CLI, but there must be a way to do this directly in Github without having to clone the repo?

I am trying to create some gh-pages and was planning on only editing in Github.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To revert to a previous version of a README.md file by only editing it via the Github UI:

1. Simply open a list of your `commits` (you will see several tabs at the top of the window containing your project's files and folders: `commits`, `branches`, `releases` etc.);
2. Select one of your previous commits in the list and click on it;
3. Click on `Browse files` button;
4. Select the file you want to copy the content from, open and copy it to the clipboard;
5. Go back to your last commit by clicking on your project's name on the top of the window and paste the copied text back to your README.md)

Comment: Thanks!   The only thing I would add is that I had to **create a new branch to open the old version** (only had a master branch), then had to switch back to `master` to paste back, otherwise worked perfectly.